# Start a command in background with `&` and have it die with the script

Tags: bash

I have a command that needs to run in the background for the duration of the script. Meaning until the rest of the script has successfully ran or met <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or been otherwise prematurely terminated.

The problem is, if I use `command &`, it keeps running even after the script has terminated, until the terminal that started it has been terminated.

Is there a way to bind the background command to the foreground script?

Comment: Put a `wait` at the end of the script.

Comment: this doesn't work, remember, I want a bg command to terminate, once its parent process has terminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43709/108618):

> To just `kill` all background jobs managed by `bash`, do
>
> ```
> kill $(jobs -p)
> ```

A basic approach is to put this line at the end of the main script, the script may never get to it though. More advanced approach is to create a trap in the main script:

```
trap 'kill $(jobs -p) 2>/dev/null' EXIT
```

Define the trap before you start the background job. The `kill` command will be run even if the main script is terminated prematurely (unless it's terminated forcefully, e.g. with SIGKILL).

But remember your job may ignore SIGTERM it gets from the `kill` in the trap.

If you want to kill a specific background job only (as opposed to all background jobs), store its PID in a variable and use the variable in the trap:

```
trap 'kill "$jpid" 2>/dev/null' EXIT

…

your_job &
jpid="$!"

…
```

I think there's a flaw though: if the main shell is terminated between `your_job &` and `jpid="$!"` then the trap will have no `$jpid` to work with. There is no such flaw in `kill $(jobs -p)`.